# mysql fulltext search cannot search dollar sign?

Tags: mysql

Going to refine the problem a bit

The description column contains USD$15, USD15 among a bunch of text.

using fulltext search IN BOOLEAN MODE but empty result returned

select * from books WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST ('USD$15' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

but

select * from books WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST ('USD15' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

is successfully......

Comment: Can you omit the dollar signs and store this as a numeric data type. It will likely be more efficient.

Comment: if 50%+ of your records contain `$10` then it will be ignored.

Comment: @juergend is this a rule for text searches?

Comment: from the Mysql doc: *In addition, words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match.*

Comment: i refine the question a bit to add clarity, adding "IN BOOLEAN MODE"

Answer (score 3):

Don't use full text search for prices, because it is designed to produce the relevance between query and appropriate text. So it allows to search for particular keywords in large amounts of texts. Index contains tokenized versions of words and can't be used for character by character match.

Use something like DECIMAL(15,4) instead and move currency setting into separate field (ENUM/TINYINT)

In worst case (you can't influence table structure and data inserted) -  you can use regular CHAR/VARCHAR with BTREE index and search via WHERE price LIKE ... approach.

Comment: i refine the question a bit to add clarity, need to search $ among a bunch of text

Comment: Use search via LIKE '%$%' + regular BTREE index but not the full-text index, as this type of search is designed to lookup the particular characters/strings.

MATCH (..) AGAINST - designed to match through *words* in their lexical meaning, like those that are from the same root, sound similar, have the same meaning and using full-text search index considers applying a lot of lexical text processing - which is not needed in your case because you are searching for characters/strings and not keywords

Comment: See more about String comparison functions here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

This may be your problem, and not the `$`

> Some words are ignored in full-text searches:
>      Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length 
>      of words that are found by full-text searches is four characters.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

You can change this setting here - but be sure to consider the consequences of all the other 3-char words which will be indexed: `my.cnf` on this setting: `ft_min_word_len = 3`

Also - @webdevbyjoss nails the actual concern - this is better handled outside of full text searching if just looking to match prices.

***UPDATE***
You are correct, you also need to add the `$` as a valid / included character or it will be ignored. From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html):

> If you want to change the set of characters that are considered word
>   characters, you can do so in several ways, as described in the
>   following list. After making the modification, you must rebuild the
>   indexes for each table that contains any FULLTEXT indexes. Suppose
>   that you want to treat the hyphen character ('-') as a word character.
>   Use one of these methods:
>
> 1. Modify the MySQL source: In myisam/ftdefs.h, see the true_word_char() and 
>      misc_word_char() macros. Add '-' to one of those macros and recompile MySQL.
> 2. Modify a character set file: This requires no recompilation. The true_word_char() macro uses a “character type” table to distinguish letters and numbers from other characters. . You can edit the contents of the  array in one of the character set XML files to specify that '-' is a “letter.” Then use the given character set for  your FULLTEXT indexes. For information about the  array format, see Section 10.3.1, “Character Definition Arrays”.
> 3. Add a new collation for the character set used by the indexed columns, and alter the columns to use that collation. For general information about adding collations, see Section 10.4, “Adding a Collation to a Character Set”. For an example specific to full-text indexing, see Section 12.9.7, “Adding a Collation for Full-Text Indexing”.

Comment: i refine the question a bit to add clarity, need to search $ among a bunch of text, ft_min_word_len=4 for my setting

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match against 3 character string, while the default is 4 (I guess that is in your case also).

It says on [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) page of MySQL docs:

`Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is four characters.`

Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) for fine tuning full-text searches:

```
For example, if you want three-character words to be searchable, 
you can set the ft_min_word_len variable by putting the following 
lines in an option file:

[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

**UPDATE:**

From MySQL documentation:

```
A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (“"”) 
characters matches only rows that contain the 
phrase literally, as it was typed. 
The full-text engine splits the phrase into words 
and performs a search in the FULLTEXT index for the words. 
Nonword characters need not be matched exactly: 
Phrase searching requires only that matches contain exactly 
the same words as the phrase and in the same order. 
For example, "test phrase" matches "test, phrase".
```

Which basically means that you could try fulltext search enclosing search
phrase in double quotes, and you could get results you need as long as dollar sign is the only special character between USD and price in your column values (also no spaces between them). However, FULLTEXT search is made for word searching, and special characters are ignored, so relying on this is very risky.

If changes in database are out of the question, maybe you can consider SPHINX for fulltext search.

Comment: i refine the question a bit to add clarity, need to search $ among a bunch of text, but you are right ft_min_word_len=4 for my setting